java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.close()V
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.close()V
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:215)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:200)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.close(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:433)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.destroy(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.freeLocalValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:220)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)

POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Calculation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>Selling Calculation</name>
    <description>Calculation API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.18.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <start-class>com.myApplication</start-class>
        <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>YYYYMMDDHHMMSS</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.ibm.db2.jcc</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>common</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
               <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>                 
             </dependency> 
               <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                       <!-- <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </dependency>-->
                
               <!--    <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>-->
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
                    <version>10.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                    <version>12.1.0</version>                 
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.15.Final</version>

                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.15.Final</version>

                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>

                </dependency>
              <!--  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>-->
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           </dependency>
       
           <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

Could you please help me resolve this error?
